# 2FA SSH authorization by a different user

Tags: ssh, security, two-factor-authentication

Is there a way to enable two-factor (2FA) SSH authorization for multiple specified users (not everyone) when their login attempts are confirmed by a *different* person?

So, on the server with users `a b c d e`, I want to enable 2FA SSH authorization for users `c d e` when their login attempts are approved by someone else, a single person in charge of this.

Since we have multiple servers, this must be applicable to multiple servers with these users.